# iterate an array into another array javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

How can I iterate an array which is into another array in javascript
I have this:

```
var arrayJS=<?php echo json_encode(startPerson($_POST['user'],$_POST['pass']))?>;

for(var i=0;i<arrayJS.length;i++)
{
        alert(arrayJS[i]);// here I have two arrays into this array
}
```

I pass the array from php:

```
        $query->execute();
        while ($res = $query->fetch()) {
            $person[] = $res[0]; //id person
            $date[]=$res[1];  // birth date person
        }
        return array($person, $date);
```

I want to take the values of the each array for separate but I don't know how.
For example
if the array has :

```
 [0]="1","2","3","4";
 [1]="1990-2-1","1980-8-3","1968-12-5","1999-1-1"
```

How I can gets the different values?

```
array id [0]="1",[1]="2",[2]="3",[3]="4"
array date [0]="1990-2-1",[1]="1980-8-3",[2]="1968-12-5",[3]="1999-1-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your example:

```
var arraya = <?php echo json_encode([["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["1990-2-1", "1980-8-3", "1968-12-5", "1999-1-1"]])?>;
var arrayb = arraya.reduce(function(previous, current){
    var len = previous.length;
    var tmp = new Array;
    for (var i = previous.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        tmp.push({"id":previous[i],"date":current[i]});
    };
    return tmp;
});
console.log(arrayb);
```

I don't know what's your demand exactly, maybe it will help you.

Comment: no it does not work for me, but thanks I've already find the  answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have to use a for into the previous for, like this:

```
var arrayJS=<?php echo json_encode(startPerson($_POST['user'],$_POST['pass']))?>;

    for(var i=0;i<arrayJS.length;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<arrayJS[i].length;j++){ 
        alert(arrayJS[i][j]) ;
    }    
    }
```